# Calculate the transfer function of an OPAMP circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

I have an OPAMP circuit that its output increase steadily without cahnge in the input. I guess the issue is in the transfer function of the circuit and its stability.
I want to calculate the transfer function of my circuit but I do not have any idea about that.
Could you please help me to calculte the transfer function?

5 volt is generated by a switching regulator called MC34063 and the opamp is a LM358 and I use a UGN3503 Hall Effect sensor
[image]

Comment: If you have built it and have this problem you need to add component values to your schematic. There is no reason that this circuit should have any significant drift so, add data sheet links to your sensor and the actual op-amp that you used. Then you need to state what the amount of drift is and how regulated your 5 volt supply is. No point calculating the TF until all the stuff I mentioned is clear.

Comment: Hello All
I add the values of components in my schematic

Comment: Ok, it is not overly complicated to extract the transfer function of this arrangement. First, the (+) pin is at a fixed 2.5-V potential or ac-grounded (0 V). You thus have an inverting filter. At dc, when all capacitors are open-circuited, the gain is \$-\frac{R_4}{R_3}\$ and then, you have one pole due to \$R_4C_2\$ and another one with \$R_5C_3\$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, notice that the voltage at \$\displaystyle\text{V}_+\$ is given by:

$$\text{V}_+=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\left(\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1}\right)}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle5}{\displaystyle\text{s}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1\left(\text{sC}_1\text{R}_2+1\right)}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle5}{\displaystyle\text{s}}\tag1$$

Where \$\displaystyle\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.

Now, notice that:

$$\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_{\text{R}_4\space\text{||}\space\text{C}_2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_--\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4\space\text{||}\space\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2}}\tag2$$

We can also see that:

$$\text{V}_\text{out}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3}}\cdot\text{V}_1=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3\text{R}_5+1}\cdot\text{V}_1\tag3$$

Combining \$\displaystyle\left(2\right)\$, \$\displaystyle\left(3\right)\$ and the fact that for ideal opamps we know that \$\displaystyle\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-\$ gives:

$$\text{V}_\text{out}=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3\text{R}_5+1}\cdot\left(\text{V}_++\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2\text{R}_4+1}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_+-\text{V}_\text{in}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\right)\tag4$$

Now, you can solve for the transfer function.

---

**Edit**, using your values I found:

$$\text{V}_\text{out}=\frac{\displaystyle100000000\left(500\left(48000+47\text{s}\right)-47\text{s}\left(200000+\text{s}\right)\text{V}_\text{i}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{s}\left(100000+\text{s}\right)\left(200000+\text{s}\right)\left(1000+47\text{s}\right)}\tag5$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. but can you explain about 5/S at the first equation?

Comment: @MMB1999 Yes, that is the Laplace transform of the voltage source at the left top of your circuit.

Comment: ok 
i am very grateful

Comment: @MMB1999 you are more than welcome!

Comment: according to your equation the system is stable and does not hava any pole at the right side of the imaginary axis. So what do you think about the increasing the output voltage without increasing in input voltage?